# Trying to hide an element when printing a page

Tags: html, css

I have a form with a button that I want to hide when I print.  I used a class (see below) which hides the button.   HOWEVER, it keeps the space where the button was which is essentially a carriage return on the printed page.  This results in extra blank lines on the printed page for each form button.

It appears that if I delete this button and keep everything else, the carriage return on the printed page goes away so the answer seems to be in here:

```
<input class="button2" type="submit" value="Delete Admission" />
```

If I delete the `class=button2` it still displays the space on the printed page.

Here is the whole thing I want to hide:

```
<span class="noprintclass">
  <form  class="noprintclass" name="delpt" method="post" action="del_pt.php" >
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id_incr'];?>" />
    <input class="button2" type="submit" value="Delete Admission" />
  </form>
</span>
```

And here is the class (I got this from a previous similar post here on stackoverflow:

```
@media print {
  .noprintclass, .noprintclass * {
    display:none !important;
  }
}
@media print {
  .button2 {
    display:none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show with screenshots?

Comment: Looks like typo or maybe some overwrite of your css in later code :D

Comment: You should not be wrapping block level element inside an inline element, use a div instead of span to wrap your form

Comment: I tried DIV - thats what I had first and it had the same problem.  Thats why I tried span.  I can go back to div but it doesnt appear thats the issue.

Comment: [How to add images?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) Make sure you're not using cached HTML and CSS.

Comment: @user2557039, Your CSS looks fine to me, I assume there is an external issue that can not be addressed here without additional info.

Comment: @Jack haha :) I'm not the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this part:

```
@media print {
    .noprintclass, .noprintclass *{
         display:none !important;
    }
}
```

to:

```
@media print {
    .noprintclass{
        display:none!important;
    }
}
```

notice removed space at '!important'

Also make sure nothing overwrites these rules later in your stylesheets.

EDIT:
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/zlajaa1/pen/WrpzJB) try to print page it works, so it might be some override of your css later on, search for any class, element name etc for display, Oh yeah, if you are changing display with php or script it might also affect.

Comment: No that didn't work.  As for overwriting elsewhere in the stylesheet, I am not sure.  What would I look for?

Comment: Have you removed space between property and !important for .button2, also merge those rules in one print rule

Comment: The whitespace around the `!important` modifier is not significant.  `none !important`, `none!important`, and `none! important` should all be equivalent.